# How can I measure a function execution time based on Truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, quorum

I'm using truffle to test my smart contract written in solidity language deployed on the Quorum blockchain. 
I want to measure the execution time of the invocation of a function using truffle. 
Is that possible in the truffle commande line?
Otherwise, is there any proposition for a solution to measure the execution time of a function in a smart contract whatever how it was invocated?

Comment: What do you mean by execution time? The actual time taken to compute a result is not usually super relevant in a blockchain, since the block time is almost always greater, and gas prevents very large computations in a single tx/block.

Comment: I mean the delay between the send time and the confirmation time

Comment: In a production network, it will mostly be a function of how much traffic there is on the chain, and the block time. Measuring it will not be of much use since it is not a constant value.